# Mongoose.js getter that inflates subdocuments on Find()?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, getter-setter

Is there an inverse of Mongoose.js validation that can inflate the subdocument when the parent is retrieved?  I may have been looking at the docs so long I'm not recognizing an existing feature for what it is.

A beauty of MongoDB is that the query specifications (e.g. `{likes: {$gt: 10, $le: 14}}` are themselves Javascript objects, and until recently have been storing them in a MongoDB instance as subdocuments.

However, upgrading from MongoDB 2.4 to 2.6, these are no longer valid to store as such, and am now getting the error: `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$or' ... is not valid for storage`

Am thus in the situation in this [Google Groups Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/uViuJsl4jP8).  The author there suggests flattening the document to a String.   This situation can also occur if the subdocuments have legitimate Javascript attributes that have embedded dots (e.g. `{"802.11g": ...}`)

That's easy enough to by specifying `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` as the getter/setter in Mongoose.js:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({   
  name: { type: String, required: false, default: "New project" },
  spec: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, set: JSON.stringify, get: JSON.parse},
});
```

But the getter only gets called if I explicitly ask for the attribute value.  The attribute is still a string underneath and gets passed as such:

```
Project.findById(req.params.projectId, function(err, project) {
  console.log("......"+(typeof project.spec))  // project.spec is an object!
  res.send(project); // project.spec is a String!
});
```

Obviously i can call `model.spec = JSON.parse(model.spec)` within each `Model.find(...)` call and for each flattened attribute but it'd be nice to do it at one central location.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/8AV6aoJzdiQ

Comment: So you want to store a data structure as a string in a document database that supports just storing the data structure anyway? I'm not sure I can really help you if you can't see what is so incredibly wrong here.

Comment: @NeilLunn, it looks like part of the data structure the OP wants to save uses keys with a dollar prefix, and so it cannot be stored straightaway.

Comment: Did you try mongoose's virtuals? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-virtual

Comment: @JorgeAranda You can escape the keys.

Comment: True, but wouldn't that still require an intermediate step after retrieval to use the fields with escaped keys as intended?

Comment: @NeilLunn Completely concur its silly to flatten data to strings .  It's just for selected subdocs. I galls me thatMongoDB crosses conceptual levels and  reserves attribute names without providing a means to escape them.  By analogy Oracle reserves the names "INDEX" and "SHARE" but will let you use them as column names if you escape them with quotes.

Comment: @NeilLunn Intriguing .. how do I escape keys?

Comment: Since you are both watching. You don't intend to query the data I gather so replacing things really does not matter or you can just filter query building by the same set of rules. But just replace the reserved characters with legal substitutes. As for what MongoDB does, well `$` is reserved for operators  ( and hence what you are storing ) as well as `.` with it's place in dot notation. So personally I would replace the reserved characters with another layer ( mongoose is not really meant to be standalone ) so at least I have the ability to query if I want to.

Comment: @user645715 You should be able to invoke the getter in `res.send` by adding the `{toJSON: {getters: true}}` option to the `ProjectSchema` definition.  Have you tried that?  You'd probably want it for `toObject` as well.

Comment: @JohnnyHK That was it!  Pls post that as the answer.Thanks!

Comment: @NeilLunn  You're right, querying on the subdocs isn't necessary in this case.  The particular challenge here is that the app uses those subdocs themselves as MongoDB query objects elsewhere.  So JSON stringify/parse is just a means to replace/restore those reserved characters for persistence. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly. The stringifiy is completely flattening as a string. You could use it to make a string, then replace, then parse back again. But storing what is really a data structure as a sting is just silly. Not to mention a waste of storage space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke your getter in `res.send` by adding the `{toJSON: {getters: true}}` option to the `ProjectSchema` definition.  You'll probably want to enable that for the `toObject` option as well for cases like passing the doc to `console.log`.

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({   
  name: { type: String, required: false, default: "New project" },
  spec: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, set: JSON.stringify, get: JSON.parse},
}, {
  toJSON: {getters: true},
  toObject: {getters: true}
});
```

Docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON).

Comment: @NeilLunn Agree keeping searchable is worthy, so went with `{set: foo, get: unfoo`} where `function foo(val) { return JSON.stringify(val).replace(/\"\$/,'\"_$'); }` and `function unfoo(val)  { return JSON.parse(val.replace(/\"_\$/,'\"$')); }`